# Text size increment not working in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

Recently I coded an Android app to test out the font settings. There I put two buttons to increment and decrement the text size of an EditText. Here is my code: (I have put Log statements for debugging purpose.)

```java
public void incSize(View v) {
    float size=e.getTextSize();
    Log.v("Size b4 inc", String.valueOf(size));
    e.setTextSize(size+1f);
    size=e.getTextSize();
    Log.v("Size after inc", String.valueOf(size));
}

public void decSize(View v) {
    float size=e.getTextSize();
    Log.v("Size b4 dec", String.valueOf(size));
    e.setTextSize(size-1f);
    size=e.getTextSize();
    Log.v("Size after dec", String.valueOf(size));
}
```

What I found was that the text size keeps on increasing even when `decSize()` method is called.
 Here is the logcat when `decSize()` is called:

```
2020-04-06 18:47:51.555 27276-27276/com.mapsup.customfonts V/Text size: 21.0
2020-04-06 18:47:51.556 27276-27276/com.mapsup.customfonts V/Text size: 23.0
```

Here is the logcat when `incSize()` is called:

```
2020-04-06 18:47:54.072 27276-27276/com.mapsup.customfonts V/Text size: 23.0
2020-04-06 18:47:54.072 27276-27276/com.mapsup.customfonts V/Text size: 27.599998
```

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because by default `getTextSize()` returns the text size in pixels while `setTextSize()` sets the text size in scaled pixels.

You should set and get the text size with the same measurement unit. You can use `setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size)` instead of `setTextSize(size)`, so the text size is set and get in `px`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX` worked. I also want to try out the first option, but Android Studio complaints that there is no method called `getScaledTextSize()`. How to get that to work?

Comment: @Puspam You are right, my bad the first option can't work since that API is marked with `@hide`. I edited my answer leaving only the right option